# Minimizing $\int_0^1\left\lvert -x + e^\varphi\right\rvert d\varphi$

Tags: integration, optimization, numerical-methods

> Which value of $x$ minimizes the following integral? $$\int_0^1\left\lvert -x + e^\varphi\right\rvert d\varphi$$

Using computational mathematics software I've seen the value of $x$ should be in interval $(0,2)$.  Unfortunately, I have no other progress towards a solution because I don't recognize this type of problem and cannot figure out how to start.

Please help me identify the method with which I am to solve this problem.  Should I be trying spline interpolation?

Comment: The straightforward way to go about it is to start by computing the integral. Afterwards you are left with a pure function of $x$ that you can minimize with the usual methods.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For $x\in[0, 2]$, the value of $|-x+e^\varphi|$ is $-x+e^\varphi$ for $\varphi\in[\text{log}(x), 1]$ and is $x-e^\varphi$ for $\varphi\in[0, \text{log}(x)]$.

Integrate from $0$ to $\text{log}(x)$ and from $\text{log}(x)$ to $1$. You will find a function of $x$. You can find its minimum.

Comment: the integral should be broken apart at $\log x$ rather than $\log 2.$

Comment: Do you know of a better argument that $1 < x < e$ than my plot of the function?